# {NameError}name 'recognize_generator' is not defined

Tags: python, get, fetch, spotify, httpwebresponse

I get an error that something is not defined, but in debugging mode I can't see what should be wrong. I am trying to do a fetch to use the Spotify API. I tried escaping the '%' but that didn't seem to bother python

[image of code in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx6Hj.png)

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials


def getSpotifyArtists(search_string):
    mode = "a"
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="",
                                                               client_secret="",
                                                               ))
    results = sp.search(q='tragoc the kid laroi', limit=20)

    if mode == "m":
        for idx, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
            print(idx, track['name'])
            number = input("number:")
            artists = results.get("tracks").get("items")[number].get("artists")
    else:
        artists = results.get("tracks").get("items")[0].get("artists")

    artist_list = []
    for artist in artists:
        artist_list.append(artist.get("name"))

    return artist_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I removed my client ID and secret because of terms of service of Spotify

Comment: Please, post the code note the screenshot of it. And include the whole traceback.